# Changes in skin do not apply

Tags: video.js

I changed a few parameters in the video-js.less file (center the big button) but the changes do not show up in the HTML page (button is still above left). I tried theses changes before in the skin designer, and they worked fine. I suppose I still do not understand the logic behind player.js skins. Isn't video-js.less the players's default skin? If it isn't, how do I connect it to the player's  tag in the HTML page? A short code example would help.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the .less file in the designer, you need to copy the resulting CSS and include it in the same html page as the player. If you're editing the .less file outside of the designer, you still need to convert it to CSS, and you can just copy and paste it into the designer to do that.

You also should make sure you've got the latest and the same version of both the less file and the video.js library.